# Passing object array with std::array vs array

Tags: c++, arrays, object, struct, stdarray

today I was discussing with my firends about correct way to pass object array in C++. Is there is any efficiency difference between these two:

```
Struct Apple {
    std::string color;
}

void colors(Apple A[]) {
    A[0].color = "red";
}

int main() {
    Appple apples[10];
    colors(apples);
    return 0;
}
```

.

```
Struct Apple {
    std::string color;
}

void colors(std::array<Apple, 10>& A) {
    A[0].color = "red";
}

int main() {
    std::array<Apple, 10> apples;
    colors(apples);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Performance-wise?

Comment: Yes. Sorry if I wasn't clear :).

Comment: In first case you are passing pointer, in second, object by reference. Are you trying to compare 2 different things?

Comment: I am just trying to figuire out which one is a better practice.

Comment: @dqmis `std::array` you don't lose anything but gain a lot

Comment: In the second case, since you have to create the std::array "wrapper" before passing it, it should slightly slower.

Comment: @Marker it happens at compile time

Comment: With O3 any sane compiler will produce the same code in both cases. So there is no difference at runtime.

Comment: 'is code A faster than code B?' - why not try it and find out.

Comment: @Killzone Kid, your are right, I was incorrectly thinking about the whole program, not just the function call. The std:array is still a class and the constructor needs to be called though the performance difference (for the program) should be very very small (negligible).

Comment: @Marker `std::array` is an aggregate so it does not have a constructor. If you put something that can be trivially initialized inside it there will only be a stack allocation and nothing more. It's a zero-cost abstraction.

Comment: @super, interesting had never looked at the documentation that closely before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those two functions produce identical code using `GCC 7.3` on `x86_64`.

Here: https://godbolt.org/g/aguVfF

First example:

```
void colors(Apple A[]) {
    A[0].color = 12;
}

_Z6colorsP5Apple: 
  mov DWORD PTR [rdi], 12
  ret
```

Second example:

```
void colors(std::array<Apple, 10>& A) {
    A[0].color = 13;
}

_Z6colorsRSt5arrayI5AppleLm10EE:
  mov DWORD PTR [rdi], 13
  ret
```

When builtin arrays are passed, they decay to a pointer to their first element. Also when objects are passed by reference that is usually implemented using a pointer.

Because a `std::array` is a *very thin* wrapper around a builtin array, its address is likely to be the same as the address to its first element. The compiler's optimizer can see right through it.

You are unlikely to find any example where using a `std::array` is slower than a builtin array because a `std::array` is basically a builtin array wrapped in ***zero cost*** syntactic sugar that leverages compile time information that the builtin version does not (like the array's size).

Answer (score 3):

You are falling into a common beginner error with both C and C++ -- you can't pass an array as an argument to a function.  The language does not allow it.  If you declare a function with an array as an argument, the compiler (silently) changes it into a poiner for you, because arrays can be implicitly converted into pointer (and generally are, in most places).

So your first example is really:

```
void colors(Apple *A) {
    A[0].color = "red";
}
```

so now it is clear that your question is really: Is there any difference in performance between passing a pointer and passing a reference?

No -- references and pointers are implemented in the same way -- as an address -- so there's no difference in performance between them.

Comment: So `void(int A[])` is not the same as `void(int *A)` ?

Comment: @dqmis:  Neither of those is a function -- they are types.

Comment: I down vote because saying that an array is passed as pointer to its first arg doesnt really prove that std::array is faster or slower, or that raw array vs std::array has other differences (safety, semantics, scale, anti-leakage, readability....)

Comment: @jotik: It is not your job to "undo" other people's right to vote.

Comment: I upvoted because even if it does not directly answers OP question (actually I think it does) it also has a complimentary value which helps to understand the problem better.

Answer (score 2):

Performance-wise, no. They are both just shuffling around a memory address and so performance is the same.

Style-wise, I'd always recommend `std::array` over C arrays. C arrays are only in C++ for backwards compatability with old code. The new stuff has the benefits of following the standard container class interfaces and so can be used with all the fancy STL generic methods in `<algorithm>` and other libraries. It also knows its own size, which is a pretty big win on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Performance-wise, it depends on the size of your array, your compiler and the compile options used. Benchmark.

When you pass a regular array, it basically decays to a pointer, so you only have the overhead of passing a pointer. If you pass an `std::array` by-copy, then you need to copy the whole array. If you pass it by reference, then you have the overhead of passing a reference (which is generally the same as passing a pointer).

I still strongly suggest you use `std::array` for type safety.

Comment: how is a `std::array` more type safe than a `Apple []` ?

Comment: Maybe not more type safe, but it knows its own size for a start.

Comment: As an added bonus if you pass by reference the compiler has more certainty about where in memory the variable is so this allows more optimizations in large programs. When you deal with pointers in compiler optimizations there is an incredible amount of uncertainty.

Comment: @jotik thats all nice features, but type safety is something different...

Comment: Note that for the `std::array` example the argument to the function is a reference, so it is not copying.

Comment: A native array passed by reference carries it's size, too.  `void colors(Apple (&)[10]);`